# Can Fortinet firewall's administrator decode SSL traffic to get logging information (Gmail/Skype/RDP password)?

Tags: vpn, fortigate, fortinet, sslvpn

Can network administrator sniff and decode SSL traffic to get sensitive information like Gmail password, Skype password, Windows email account, or Remote Desktop .... ?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are explicitly off-topic here, as are questions about bypassing network security or policies.

Comment: @RonMaupin I just edit the question to fit the rule.

Comment: ?!? Then, you would be the network administrator, and you would know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not a VPN tunnel is used, network administrators cannot inspect SSL traffic unless they either have access to the server's private key or use SSL deep inspection.

SSL deep inspection replaces the server certificate and requires an alternative CA root certificate to be installed on all clients. You can easily detect this by inspecting the certificate chain. SSL deep inspection uses Man-in-the-Middle decryption and reencryption, and should be well documented and policed inside the company.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer, "You can easily detect this by inspecting the certificate chain", how can I do that? They just tell me to install FortiClient on my laptop and tell me to connect to the VPN, so is that safe?

Comment: Also, all the methods mentioned by Zac are not possible if the encryption uses TLS 1.3.

Comment: @Crown thank you very much! that's great new for web browser. But I just connected to a Windows Server 2008 R2 RDP and it's not TLS 1.3, still a bit worry.

Comment: @joe E.g. in Firefox, you could right-click on the web page background -> Page information -> Security -> Show certificate -> Details.

Comment: @Cown Why not? PFS does not protect against MitM.

Comment: @Zac67 What is PFS? No passive man in the middle attack is still possible with TLS 1.3, that's true. But passive mode decryption will no longer be possible since the RSA key exchange has been removed.

Comment: @Cown PFS=Perfect Forward Secrecy=additional DH session key - seems I need to look more into 1.3.

Comment: @Zac67 Good read: https://blog.gigamon.com/2018/05/10/tls-1-3-is-moving-forward-what-you-need-to-know-today-to-get-ready/